# AWS new console doesn't have Load Balancer Redirect option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am trying to redirect all incoming requests from http to https. I have multiple internal servers and I am trying to do this with AWS load balancer. I found that this can be done using Application load balancer for which I have to define the target group.
I have EC2 instances and a application load balancer which is targeting to the instances. This load balancer having a ssl certificate for https endpoints and I added another Application load balancer which will redirect the traffic from http to https and for port 443 it will just forward the request to the next one.

I see when i define target group for next application load balancer it just gives option to add network load balancer and there is no redirect option as shown in AWS documentation
[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#redirect-actions).

I want to use old console but there is no option for that.

can someone help to solve this issue?

I tried following AWS documentation but it seems documentation is not up to date and there is no redirect UI as shown in docs.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, Actually it needs only one Application load balancer and need to add port mappings for 443. After saving this there is option to add listner which allows re-direct option.
Earlier I was trying to add re-direct option while creating the load balancer which was not allowing but interesting thing is it allows one load balancer is created.